# Ставится ли запятая? Может ли это быть приложением?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Я должен был догадаться, что ты влюблён в неё(,) ещё в тот день, когда ты её упомянул.

"Что ты влюблён в неё" - это приложение?

Answer (score 4):

Это изъяснительное придаточное предложение.

*Я должен был догадаться* (о чем?), ***что ты влюблен в нее***, еще в тот день, когда ты ее упомянул.

Answer (score 2):

> Может ли это быть приложением?

"Ты влюблён в неё" — придаточное изъяснительное. Придаточные изъяснительные отвечают на вопросы **дополнения**, то есть на вопросы косвенных падежей.

А приложение — это **определение**, выраженное существительным. Как правило, приложение согласуется с определяемым словом в числе и падеже.

Как говорится, почувствуйте разницу.

Answer (score -2):

Это не приложение, а обстоятельство.

Я должен был догадаться, что ты влюблён в неё (когда?) ещё в тот день, когда ты её упомянул. **Запятая не нужна.**

Comment: По-моему, "еще в тот день" относится к "догадаться". Я должен был догадаться (когда?) еще в тот день. Это придаточное предложение в середине главного.

Comment: влюблен (когда?) еще в тот день, когда упомянул ее.

Comment: Да неужели так говорят: "влюблен в тот день"?! Здесь: Я   должен был догадаться в тот день, когда ты ее упомянул.